# Can variable-substitution-syntaxes be unified?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

Can these two variable-substitution-syntaxes combined into one?

```
rm "$s_a/$domain.conf" 2>/dev/null
rm "$s_e/$domain.conf" 2>/dev/null
```

like:

```
rm "$s_{a,e}/$domain.conf" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I did a mistake not to test this. I also remember I got working results in a similar case with `${}` syntax. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can*, but not while quoting the expansion (since double-quotes preserve the literal meaning of *most* "special characters", braces included):

```
rm $s_{a,e}/$domain.conf
```

expands in steps to:

```
rm $s_a/$domain.conf $s_e/$domain.conf
```

and then to the corresponding values.

Within double-quotes, the braces are left alone, so the line expands to:

> rm *(value of $s_)*{a,e}/*(value of $domain)*.conf

Quoting prevents unintentional expansions, notably word splitting and filename expansion. You could work around word splitting by unsetting `$IFS`, and could work around filename expansion with `set -f`, combining to:

```
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=
set -f
rm $s_{a,e}/$domain.conf 2>/dev/null
IFS=$oIFS
set +f
```

Comment: I can't say why other people voted as they did, just that you could help yourself by demonstrating some testing on your part and point out where you were surprised or confused.

Comment: I fully agree this should generally be done.

Comment: To not have to bother about whether `set -f` was in effect previously, or waht `IFS` was set to: `( IFS=; set -f; rm ... )`